# SQL query to select from same column but multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table.

```
id  customer        product 
1   Tizag           Pen 
4   Gerald Garner   19" LCD Screen  
5   Tizag           19" LCD Screen
```

I want to select the customer who has both "Pen" and '19" LCD Screen'. So, the result with be customer 'Tizag'.

How can I do this.

Thanks And Regards,
Rupak Banerjee.

Comment: Your table structure looks wonky.

Comment: As Lion suggests, you should have customer and product in separate tables joined by ID.

Comment: Normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: My actual table collects the feature of the items in the table. This table was just an example of what actually I was looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naively:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM tblname t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE product = 'Pen' AND customer = t1.customer)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE product = '19" LCD Screen' AND customer = t1.customer)
```

But I think in general, there's more to this kind of question and you need to give more details as to the environment and the range of parameters.

Please note, that I am not necessarily advocating this approach but I give it (and denote it as naive, meaning that it is very simple and takes very little into account in terms of table indexing) because:

1. It's very portably ANSI - nothing special going on
2. It is very clear (without joins) for a SQL beginner to parse and get understanding in a set-based manner
3. It is obviously extensible by parameters (perhaps for dynamic SQL)

The drawbacks are that:

1. Table scans, who knows how bad this execution plan is going to be
2. Correlated subqueries, relating to problems with #1
3. Verbosity, repetition
4. Any SELECT * (even inside an EXISTS) is likely to raise an eyebrow

Comment: This will just return all the customers if there are rows with those products

Comment: @MiMo It performs exactly as required: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64077/stackoverflow-com-questions-9708925-sql-query-to-select-from-same-column-but-mult

Comment: @MiMo Yes, this should work fine. However, it suffers from the same problem as my answer, that the query needs to change depending on the number of products. Except this uses subqueries instead of joins, which makes it slower. ;)

Comment: @ryan if you are just checking if that value exists in dataset then exists is faster than join.

Comment: @rs everything depends, but in general I would not use this approach.  I give some more detail in my expansion of my answer.  Depending on what the question really is, I would have a more optimized approach.  In SQL Server I increasingly use table-valued parameters, which would result in a different style of answer.

Comment: Nope, this one is the right solution. And, better than another with correct solution as this query it's easy to go on adding parameters dynamically.

Comment: @user1269939 Although it's easy to do that, you need to understand that there are consequences of this approach, which is why I added some caveats to my answer.

Comment: @CadeRoux: sorry, I did not see the `AND customer = t1.customer` conditions

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT customer FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING( customer )
WHERE t1.product = 'Pen'
AND t2.product = '19" LCD Screen'
```

However, the query needs to change if you change the number of products. There might be a better way to do this, but I think this will work.

Comment: The only problem with this query is it seems to be limiting the parameters. What will happen if there are more than 2 products to be selected?

Comment: @user1269939 That's what I meant when I said the query needs to change if you have more products. You should probably take the advice in the comments on your question about splitting the tables and normalizing your data; then this becomes a much simpler query.

Comment: @user1269939 I refer you to the comment in my answer - you need to give more information about how you expect to pass in the required parameters, or whether it is perhaps any customer who has all possible products.  You need to put a little more effort into asking a well-defined question if you want a well-defined answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER
FROM YOURTABLE yt1,YOURTABLE yt2
WHERE yt1.customer=yt2.customer
  AND yt1.product='Pen'
  AND yt2.product=''19" LCD Screen';
```

Comment: This gives all the customer name. By requirement is, the name  of that customer who owns both Pen and 19" LCD Screen

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select customer
from tablename
where product = 'Pen' AND
      customer IN (select customer from tablename where product = '19" LCD Screen');
```